# Power BI DAX: Calculate the sum of the following week

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a power bi dax that calculates the hours based on selected start of week. I am currently getting the correct value for week 1, however, week 2 or the following week returns the total sum of entire rows. I select the start of week using a slicer. Below is the dax I am currently using for week 1 and week 2:

Week 1 DAX Measure:

```
 Week1Duration = 
    VAR SelectedWeekStart = SELECTEDVALUE('01_Date'[Start of Week])
    VAR Week1StartDate = CALCULATE(MIN('01_Date'[CalendarDate]), '01_Date'[Start of Week] = SelectedWeekStart)
    VAR Week1EndDate = Week1StartDate + 6
    RETURN
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(FactTable[Duration]),
            'FactTable'[Date] >= Week1StartDate && 'FactTable'[Date] <= Week1EndDate
        )
```

Week 2 DAX Measure:

```
Week2Duration = CALCULATE(SUM('FactTable'[Duration]), REMOVEFILTERS('01_Date'[Start of Week]), '01_Date'[Week ID] = MAX('01_Date'[Week ID]) + 1)
```